# Print the values of matcher for Regular expression to logcat

Tags: android, regex

Is this  below code correct I am getting error  if I print matcher.group(0). Am I print the values in correct way?Plz help.Logcat error is below.

```
 String GetCddata=<p><a href="http://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/2db83fcf95c5fc036a00abfb412f50e4.jpg">
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-12" src="http://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/2db83fcf95c5fc036a00abfb412f50e4.jpg?w=529" alt="2db83fcf95c5fc036a00abfb412f50e4" />
</a><a href="https://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/0e397a47f88e18f8fb91d17db18c7edd-copy.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4" src="http://myimagefactorycollection.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/0e397a47f88e18f8fb91d17db18c7edd-copy.jpg?w=529" alt="0e397a47f88e18f8fb91d17db18c7edd - Copy" />
</a></p><br /> <a rel="nofollow" href="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/gocomments/myimagefactorycollection.wordpress.com/3/"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://feeds.wordpress.com/1.0/comments/myimagefactorycollection.wordpress.com/3/" />
</a> <img alt="" border="0" src="http://pixel.wp.com/b.gif?host=myimagefactorycollection.wordpress.com&#038;blog=75018866&#038;post=3&#038;subd=myimagefactorycollection&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1" width="1" height="1" />
    ]];

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\<a href=)(.*?)\\>");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(GetCddata);
Log.v("dd",matcher.group(0));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKpOD.png

Comment: you are getting an error : Illegal State Exception no successful match so far

Answer (score 0):

group:

```
public String group()
```

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match. For a
> matcher m with input sequence s, the expressions m.group() and
> s.substring(m.start(), m.end()) are equivalent.
>
> Note that some patterns, for example a*, match the empty string. This
> method will return the empty string when the pattern successfully
> matches the empty string in the input.
>
> Specified by:     group in interface MatchResult Returns: The (possibly
> empty) subsequence matched by the previous match, in string form
>
> **Throws:**   IllegalStateException - If no match has yet been attempted, or if the previous match operation failed

Source :[docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group())

**Suggestion:** check your Regex pattern, enclose your `Log.v();` inside a `try...catch` block